# I only want to have the click add one count, not repeated additions to the content

Tags: javascript

In class we are learning JavaScript, and we have to find out how to stop the button click from repeatedly adding the count with .insertbefore
I'm stumped as to why it continually inserts the count.

```
      function clicked() {
            console.log("Clicked!");
            var count = "Node Count: "+countChildren(document.getElementById("content"));
            console.log(count);
      try {
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = count;
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].insertBefore(span, document.getElementById("content"));
      } catch(ex) {
            console.log("error "+ex)
           }
      }
```

Comment: not enough info. how is clicked called? probably from a "dom modified" callback. in any case if this is for class you need to invest more time figuring it out yourself, for example use the debugger etc.

Comment: Why are you using insertBefore? All you need to do is to put a div or span with id="someVar" and then assign the innerHTML of the someVar tag to count

Answer (score 0):

Modify your button HTML like this

```
<input type ="button" onclick="clicked(); this.onclick=null;"/>
```

so when once click function is executed, this will stop further clicking actions

Comment: You're assuming that the click handler is wired up using an attribute.  This isn't applicable when using JQuery event handlers and Knockout data-binds

Comment: @RobertSlaney the question is tagged with javascript only

Comment: `document.getElementById('id').addEventListener( 'click', function() { } );`  The element's onclick will still be undefined.  This is pure javascript.  JQuery and Knockout were just examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the node is already added.

```
 var count = ...
 if ( count !== 0 ) {
      return;
 }

 try {
     ...
 }
 catch(ex) {
     ...
 }
```